# compile error about <typeinfo> usage on boost library

Tags: c++, boost, typeinfo

When I migrate my project to c++17 from c++11, the builds on the projects failed with some errors about  usage. I suspect the boost library, because the errors I get refer to the classes related with the boost library. I am sharing every detail about the compile error below.

#### Configurations

- Boost Version: 1.73.0
- Selected schema: [image]
- Xcode version: Version 12.4 (12D4e)
- Apple Clang

#### Reproduce Steps

1. Set C++ language dialectic as C++17[-std=c++17] : [image]
2. Delete derived data folder
3. Clean ccache
4. Clean Build Folder
5. Pod update
6. Build started
7. Build failed: "You need to include  before using the 'typeid' operator"

Error List:

1.Error in stl_type_index.hpp line 90

```
inline stl_type_index() BOOST_NOEXCEPT
   : data_(&typeid(void))//You need to include <typeinfo> before using the 'typeid' operator
{}
```

2.Error in stl_typ_index.hpp line 246

```
    template <class T>
inline stl_type_index stl_type_index::type_id() BOOST_NOEXCEPT {
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::remove_reference<T>::type no_ref_t;
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::remove_cv<no_ref_t>::type no_cvr_prefinal_t;

    #  if (defined(__EDG_VERSION__) && __EDG_VERSION__ < 245) \
        || (defined(__sgi) && defined(_COMPILER_VERSION) && _COMPILER_VERSION <= 744)

        // Old EDG-based compilers seem to mistakenly distinguish 'integral' from 'signed integral'
        // in typeid() expressions. Full template specialization for 'integral' fixes that issue:
        typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::conditional<
            boost::is_signed<no_cvr_prefinal_t>::value,
            boost::make_signed<no_cvr_prefinal_t>,
            boost::type_identity<no_cvr_prefinal_t>
        >::type no_cvr_prefinal_lazy_t;

        typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME no_cvr_prefinal_t::type no_cvr_t;
    #else
        typedef no_cvr_prefinal_t no_cvr_t;
    #endif

    return typeid(no_cvr_t); // You need to include <typeinfo> before using the 'typeid' operator
}
```

3. Error in stl_type_index.hpp line 261

```cpp
    template <class T>
    inline stl_type_index stl_type_index::type_id_with_cvr() BOOST_NOEXCEPT {
        typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME boost::conditional<
            boost::is_reference<T>::value ||  boost::is_const<T>::value || boost::is_volatile<T>::value,
            detail::cvr_saver<T>,
            T >::type type;
    
        return typeid(type);//You need to include <typeinfo> before using the 'typeid' operator
    }
```

4. Error in stl_type_index line 270

```cpp
    #ifdef BOOST_NO_RTTI
        return value.boost_type_index_type_id_runtime_();
    #else
        return typeid(value); // You need to include <typeinfo> before using the 'typeid' operator
    #endif
```

5. Errors in sp_counted_impl line 178 and 183

```cpp
    virtual void * get_deleter( sp_typeinfo_ const & ti ) BOOST_SP_NOEXCEPT
    {
        return ti == BOOST_SP_TYPEID_(D)? &reinterpret_cast<char&>( del ): 0; // You need to include <typeinfo> before using the 'typeid' operator
    }

    virtual void * get_local_deleter( sp_typeinfo_ const & ti ) BOOST_SP_NOEXCEPT
    {
        return ti == BOOST_SP_TYPEID_(D)? boost::detail::get_local_deleter( boost::addressof( del ) ): 0; // You need to include <typeinfo> before using the 'typeid' operator
    }
```

6. Error in shared_ptr.hpp line 1011

```cpp
template<class D, class T> D * basic_get_deleter( shared_ptr<T> const & p ) BOOST_SP_NOEXCEPT
{
    return static_cast<D *>( p._internal_get_deleter(BOOST_SP_TYPEID_(D)) ); // You need to include <typeinfo> before using the 'typeid' operator
}
```

7. Errors in shared_ptr.hpp line 1168 and 1173

```cpp
template<class D, class T> D * basic_get_local_deleter( D *, shared_ptr<T> const & p ) BOOST_SP_NOEXCEPT
{
    return static_cast<D *>( p._internal_get_local_deleter( BOOST_SP_TYPEID_(local_sp_deleter<D>) ) ); //You need to include <typeinfo> before using the 'typeid' operator
}

template<class D, class T> D const * basic_get_local_deleter( D const *, shared_ptr<T> const & p ) BOOST_SP_NOEXCEPT
{
    return static_cast<D *>( p._internal_get_local_deleter( BOOST_SP_TYPEID_(local_sp_deleter<D>) ) ); //You need to include <typeinfo> before using the 'typeid' operator
}
```

#### Research Steps

1. Update boost version. I applied the two boost compile methods suggested in the articles below.

   - https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/08/07/compiling-boost-gcc-clang-macos/
   - https://phylogeny.uconn.edu/tutorial-v2/part-1-ide-project-v2/setting-up-the-boost-c-library-v2/#
2. Clean ccache, clean build folder, delete Xcode derived data then start build after applying each solution
3. Builds failed. Compiler errors are same with older errors.
   Do you have any suggestions about the include  issue? Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: what error? what code? Please include a [mcve] and the compiler error message

Comment: Please do not use links or images for code. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am going to add error codes into post.

Answer (score 0):

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

> The header `<typeinfo>` must be included before using `typeid`

Which standard includes include which others is unspecified and can change with any update.  So you previously had `<typeinfo>` being dragged in by something else, and now you don't.

That seems to be what the error message is telling you (the name of the file with angle brackets got removed from the markdown, but is visible as the comment you showed later).  You need to include this header before the code causing the error is reached.  Understand?

Comment: If that condition arises from /just/ including boost headers, then you might consider that a deficiency of the respective boost library headers, and could report it to the developers/maintainers.

Comment: The condition arises from just including boost libraries. Thank you for your suggestion. I am going to report this issue to developers. When the problem is solved, I am going to share the solution here.

Comment: Yes, report it to Boost, and add the `#include` to fix it.